# Find a character from a column in data.frame separated by ","

Tags: regex, r

how  to find if a gene "Itln1" is present  in a data.frame

sample data.frame

```
chr   start   end         Genes   
1      8401    8410      Mndal,Mnda,Ifi203,Ifi202b    
2      8001    8020      Cyb5r1,Adipor1,Klhl12    
3      4001    4020      Alyref2,Itln1,Cd244 
3      4018    5109      Itln1,DCAF8,PEA15A")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep`

```
grep('\\bItln1\\b', x1$Genes)
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: @user20650 It is the word boundary.  Suppose you have a different gene with `12Itln12`, without the `\\b`, it will match that element.  For example.  `grep('\\bItln1\\b', c('12Itln12', 'Itln1'))` and  `grep('Itln1', c('12Itln12', 'Itln1'))`

Comment: Great thanks akrun...(so thats what is meant by word boundary (duh))

Comment: @user20650 No problem.  Perhaps this link might help http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Cheers akrun... great link

Comment: @user20650 By reading into that, I got some new info as well :-)

Comment: @akrun,  suppose if i want to look for a list of genes instead of Itln1 (for e.g. (Itln1, Adipor1), how can it be done.

Comment: @Kryo You can use `paste` to paste elements Suppose `v1 <- c('Itln1', 'Adipor1');  grep(paste0('\\b', v1, '\\b', collapse='|'), x1$Genes)`